# Rename all the files "file.txt" in directory with multiple subdirectories

Tags: command-line, files, directory

If I have a `directory1` which has a "file.txt" and subdirectories: "week", "today", "last month". In "week" and "last month" is also "file.txt".

```
directory1/
    file.txt
    week/
        file.txt
    today/
    last month/
        file.txt
```

How could I, using only one line command in terminal with the command `mv` or `rename.ul`, rename every "file.txt" in "directory1" into "new_file.txt" ?

Comment: You probably want `mv`, not `rm`, don't you?

Answer (score 3):

Yet another one to avoid absolute path trickery:

```
find directory1 -name file.txt -execdir mv {}  new_file.txt \;
```

`execdir` will run the specified command from the subdirectory containing the matched file. This even eliminates the need for quoting the filename, which we know to not contain any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
find directory1/ -type f  -name file.txt | while read f; do d=$(dirname $f); mv "$d"/file.txt "$d"/new_file.txt; done
```

Comment: You forgot to add quotes around *$f* - `$(dirname "$f")`. You also forgot to remove the *echo*. :)

Comment: damn you for getting there first :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
find directory1 -name file.txt -exec bash -c 'mv "{}" "$(dirname "{}")/new_file.txt"' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Still another way:

```
find directory1 -name file.txt -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/file\.txt/new_file\.txt/'
```